# Slick CSS carousel/slider vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I am trying to get slick slider as an auto scrolling carousel working in a webpage I am building. What I am trying to achieve is [**this effect**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WyWrJG), a horizontal line of images that scrolls slowly all the time.

When I run my code, however, the images load in a vertical stack, with no scrolling at all. I have copied the slick folder into the same folder as my `index.html`. What is it that I am missing here?

I have this in my CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

.slider {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  .parent-slide {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

.slider:before,
.slider:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  /*makes the linkes behind clickable.*/
}

.slider:before {
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.slider:after {
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

and this in my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/stills/apt.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/stills/apt.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/stills/apt.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/stills/apt.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/stills/apt.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/stills/apt.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/stills/apt.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.slider').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 0,
        speed: 2200,
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        cssEase: 'linear'
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right, the problem is only that in the example you showed the `CSS` is written in `LESS`.

[image: css less]

> **LESS**
> Less (sometimes stylized as LESS) is a dynamic preprocessor style sheet language that can be compiled into Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) and run on the client side or server side.
> — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(stylesheet_language)

The problem in your code is the cascade written code:

```css
.slider{
  /* .. */
  .parent-slide{padding:15px;}
  img{display: block;margin:auto;}
}
```

This kind of code is **not** supported by `CSS`.

Here is the example with *normal* `CSS`:

```js
window.onload=function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
  autoplay:true,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  speed: 2200,
  arrows:false,
  centerMode:true, 
  slidesToShow:5,
  slidesToScroll:3,
  cssEase: 'linear'
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.slider .parent-slide {
  padding: 15px;
}
.slider img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.slider:before,
.slider:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  /*makes the links behind clickable.*/
}
.slider:before {
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
.slider:after {
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #000000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick-theme.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://stevensegallery.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://placecage.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://stevensegallery.com/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
</div>
```

*It always helps to look at the real source code with your [Web Developer Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector).*

---

To see how the code has to be implemented into an HTML file see the follow code and paste it into an empty HTML file: https://pastebin.com/uKXzf86g

Comment: Thanks! this runs great here, obviously, but in my page it gives me giant vertical images still.  Does the `window.onload=function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
  autoplay:true,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  speed: 2200,
  arrows:false,
  centerMode:true, 
  slidesToShow:5,
  slidesToScroll:3,
  cssEase: 'linear'
  });`
}; function go in a js file?

Comment: Make sure that the `<link />`  and `<script />` I posted as well are load before the `windows.onload` function. The function call itself you can embed like you did above in `<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- [...] --> </script>`

Comment: I have added this, and now the page never loads.. it just sits at the loading stage. Please excuse my idiocy, what could this be? I have copied your code exactly

Comment: Again, check with your [Web Devoloper Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector) the `<iframe>` how it gets actually implemented here in SO. Also there in the [`Console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Use_the_Inspector_from_the_Web_Console) you can double check if it throws an error message.

Comment: aha, I see `slick.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
2bootstrap.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
plugin.js:22 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at plugin.js:22
(anonymous) @ plugin.js:22
scripts.js:227 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at scripts.js:227`

Comment: So your system can't resolve the `//`, just reaplace it with a `https://`.

Comment: less errors! `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
    at window.onload (index.html:185)`

Comment: No sure if the `jquery` or the `slick` script didn't get loaded. I just copied the `html` from the example `<iframe>`: https://pastebin.com/GFWX9PJk try it! *You need to replace the `//` again.

Comment: Ok! copying the pastebin loads as expected, but does not move.

Comment: Last try: https://pastebin.com/uKXzf86g copy it into an empty `html` file

Comment: Success! Now i just need to merge that with my existing code. thank you very much for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `$(document).ready(function(){` used in the html page. Somehow it is not considering that to utilise the slick properties set.

If you try like below in your html file, it will definitely work!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
   $('.slider').slick({
       autoplay:true,
       autoplaySpeed: 0,
       speed: 2200,
       arrows:true,
       centerMode:true, 
       slidesToShow:3,
       slidesToScroll:1,
       cssEase: 'linear'
   });
};
</script>
```